# XSD Java: получить структуру

Tags: java, xsd

Всем добрый день.
Встала задача из XSD получить результирующую структуру XML. Если конкретнее, то из схемы нужно получить последовательность тэгов, что за чем идет, что у чего родитель и проч. Т. е. из

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="cType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">

            </element>
            <element name="2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">

            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="root" type="cType"></element>
</schema>
```

получить

```
<root>
    <1>
        ...
    </1>
    <2>
        ...
    </2>
</root>
```

в виде списка или аналогичной структуры.
Пользуюсь пакетом com.sun.xml.xsom, но что-то не смогла найти ничего по этому поводу (может, и проглядела). Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобным? Может, есть уже готовые решения?
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо

P.S. Да, я знаю про JAXB и XJC, но это не подходит, так как нецелесообразно для одних и тех же данных из одной и той же БД генерировать кучу разных классов на каждую XSD, коих может быть и десять, и двадцать.

Comment: генерить налету ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, Вы имеет ввиду в runtime? JAXB это позволяет? И тут встает вопрос тогда с RowMapper'ом

Comment: тебе же нужно получить иерархию тегов, верно? что за чем идет и все, больше ничего, мапить на них ничего не надо. я правильно понял ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, идея такая: прилетает XSD, по ней формируется иерархия тэгов и потом формируется XML с данными из БД в соответствии с этой иерархией. То есть как бы вроде мапить ничего не надо, а вроде и надо. Я, наверное, немного криво объясняю, пардон

Comment: А почему бы не описать сущности, потом с помощью ORM получить данные, и после уже экспортировать в нужный формат ?